# Issue with rewrite url and hash scrolling

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, zurb-foundation, magellan

I am building a site using Foundation 5, PHP, HTML5 and CSS. I am using the [Magellan Nav component from Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html) and it works as expected.

The issue I am having is that when I click on a nav link instead of just scrolling and adding a hash to the current url, it changes the hash of the window location but it also removes the current section by using (I think) the base href.

I tried changing the href of the Magellan links to `./habitaciones/#xxxxx` instead of just `#xxxxx`, but then the script stops working and the smooth scroll doesn't work.

Is it an .htaccess setting, changing the base href or I should modify the magellan script?

My .htaccess is as follows:
RewriteEngine       On

```
RewriteRule         ^/?$                    index.php       [L]
RewriteRule         ^habitaciones/?$        habitaciones.php    [L]
```

You can check the specific [section here](http://zebradm.mx/dev/aluxes.com.mx/habitaciones/).

Comment: htaccess can not reach the URL hashes. Those are entirely client side.

Comment: So, you say that what's affecting the URL is the magellan script? Thanks for the edit btw.